# How to print date in GMT format?

Tags: java

I am trying to print the current date in `GMT` Format but it is getting only in `IST` format.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException { 
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz");

    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println("Local Time: " + sdf.format(date));

    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    System.out.println("GMT Time  : " + sdf.format(date));
    Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz").parse(sdf.format(date));  
    System.out.println("\t"+date1); 
}
```

This is my output

`Local Time: 2019 Apr 08 19:48:23 IST
GMT Time  : 2019 Apr 08 14:18:23 GMT
    Mon Apr 08 19:48:23 IST 2019`

but i want to like this `2019 Apr 08 14:18:23 GMT` after parsing the string to date.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533484/how-to-convert-java-util-date-to-gmt-format

Comment: Why are you using `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`? Why not use `java.time` classes? These are obsolete.

Comment: @LppEdd read clearly my question.. in this line `Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz").parse(sdf.format(date));` it is not getting GMT

Comment: @RealSkeptic can you show me example please

Comment: @niteesh look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122608/simpledateformat-parse-loses-timezone You need to use `setTimeZone`

Comment: I'd ask a moderator to "swap" the currently choosen duplicate with the above one

Comment: Your second print seems correct, so it's not very clear what problem you are having. Note that a `java.util.Date` does *not* contain a timezone, so parsing to one will lose you that information. The `toString` output is misleading and should not be used (and neither should the class itself, really).